# Your role does not give you permission to view this page when accessing Netsuite restlet

Tags: netsuite

I have a restlet deployed on my netsuite site, and cannot seem to reach it with any role outside of the Administrator.

> Your role does not give you permission to view this page

The role I'm trying to use is setup as a web services only role, with the following setup:

[image: Setup permissions]

Answer (score 4):

Restlets are not "Web Services" in NetSuite parlance. "Web Services" in NetSuite *strictly* means their SOAP API and *nothing* more. You will need to remove the "Web Services Only" setting on the Role in order to use it in Restlets.

Answer (score 2):

Please check  with script deployment Audience section.

Make sure this script is available for the particular roles in **audience** section in **script Deployment**.

[image]

Comment: This is also a good suggestion to check as this can trip up even experienced NetSuite devs from time to time, but you will still need to uncheck "Web Services Only" on the Role as well.